# Can I choose any reference frame?

Tags: reference-frames, relativity, machs-principle

I'm a horrible noob at anything past mechanics, so please bear with me.

According to Einstein's theory of relativity (at least as it is known in "popular science" (lowercase)), mass-full objects can't move faster than the speed of light. They become infinitely massive which results in the F required to accelerate them to approach infinity.

Moreover, I heard, that according to his theory (not sure which one), one can choose any frame of reference for any physics calculation. If I decide, for whatever reason, that my nose is stationary and everything else moves relative to it all the physics would still work.

However, point 2 seems to contradict point 1.

I decide that my nose is the "stationary frame of reference". Then I twirl around in a circle at 60RPM. The stars are going to be going at more than $c$ (the sun will be moving at 939 474 627 996 meters/second (2*pi*1 AU/second) is around $3000 c$).

Why does this not work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chosing a reference frame in which the earth is at rest and doesn't rotate](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/603/)